# boost sem_timedwait() supported on win7 platform?

Tags: boost

can someone tell me the headers I need to define to resolve timespec struct
when using sem_timedwait() on win7 platform ...is it supported ?
note I not using ptheads ... or interprocess semaphore 
using boost 1.5 libraries ...

here is snippet of what I have but not sure what else to include

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>  
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>  
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>    
#include <semaphore.h>   
#include <time.h>  
...

sem_init(&sema, 0, 0);      
sem_init(&semb, 0, 0);  
...

struct timespec timeout = { 0, 0 };
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout );
timeout.tv_sec += 5; //5 second timeout 
CU_ASSERT_TRUE(sem_timedwait(&sema,&timeout));   // released by another boost::thread
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support the pthreads standard natively, so you will have to use an alternative, such as [pthreads-win32](https://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) for example.

If want to use boost, then it's better to use what's in boost, and in that case you should replace the use of the pthreads semaphore in your code with the [boost.interprocess semaphore](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html).